# E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file

Tags: apt-get, certbot, debian-buster

Since i installed certbot on Debian 10, it always shows this error:

```
root@HypeTime:/home/sinusbot# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease
Hit:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease
Hit:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease
Ign:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::15 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Does someone know how to fix this error?

Comment: That said, why are you using an Ubuntu repository on a Debian system?  Especially when there is [already a certbot package in the main Debian repository](https://packages.debian.org/buster/certbot), which is what [the official instructions tell you to use](https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/debianbuster-apache.html).

Comment: The "focal" version is nout out yet.
Maybe you should revert back to a previous Ubuntu version in the sources.list (change focal to disco in the file pointing to this PPA), while still avoiding using an Ubuntu repo on a Debian system.

Comment: Same issue here. Focal gives the error `module 'acme.challenges' has no attribute 'TLSSNI01'`

Answer (score 275):

I got rid of the error message on Ubuntu 20.04 by removing the ppa repository. It took me a long time to find out the exact command argument, so this might help others :-).
I used the command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:certbot/certbot
```

After that, the following commands do not generate any errors:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: for other ways to remove the ppa repository (including GUI tool Software & Updates) you could check [How to list and remove PPA repository on Ubuntu 20.04 Linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-list-and-remove-ppa-repository-on-ubuntu-20-04-linux)

Comment: This answer is out of date.  See the certbot instructions.

Comment: `Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:certbot/certbot'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
`

Comment: @BlakeMcBride if you mean some specific instructions, could you share a link?

Comment: I'm guessing he means these: https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal - the command to remove from the ppa works, but those are the new certbot install instructions.

Comment: Its work for Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS thanks @jimbod119

Comment: In case of add-apt-repository command not found, run: sudo apt-get install software-properties-common

Answer (score 39):

I stumbled into these messages

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot
This is the PPA for packages prepared by Debian Let's Encrypt Team and backported for Ubuntu.

Note: Packages are only provided for currently supported Ubuntu releases.
 More info: https://launchpad.net/~certbot/+archive/ubuntu/certbot
Press [ENTER] to continue or Ctrl-c to cancel adding it.

Hit:1 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:2 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [111 kB]
Get:3 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [98.3 kB]
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [107 kB]
Ign:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal InRelease
Get:6 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages [588 kB]
Get:7 http://ca-central-1.ec2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages [666 kB]
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/certbot/certbot/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

by following [Ubuntu 18.04 certbot installation instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) on Ubuntu 20.04.

I should've followed the [Ubuntu 20.04 certbot installation instructions](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04), which avoid the command sequence `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:certbot/certbot` followed by `sudo apt install python-certbot-nginx` and simply execute

```
sudo apt install certbot python3-certbot-nginx
```

Note that the 20.04-friendly command uses `python3` in the command, and not just `python`.

To be fair, I [wasn't the only one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61438043) dealing with [this issue](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/7951). [This other post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) about solutions that offer the `-r` option to remove repositories helped me figure out in which direction a solution to my issue could be.

See @vinyll's answer for "A [one-liner Certbot install](https://github.com/vinyll/certbot-install) is available with the uninstaller included. Works also on Ubuntu 20.04." I did not follow that route because I'm not to keen to uninstall packages without being absolutely certain what they're dependencies for. Since I wasn't 100% certain at the time, it was easier to just follow the installation instructions for the proper OS than uninstall it risking eliminating needed dependencies without being aware.

Answer (score 30):

The latest source works just fine and can be installed with a [one-liner to install certbot](https://github.com/vinyll/certbot-install#how-to-install).

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/vinyll/certbot-install/master/install.sh | bash
```

That solved for me, and there's an uninstall also when certbot PPA will be fixed again.

Comment: while this is still working and makes sense when willing to install the latest version, PPAs now released an upgrade that installs certbot on Focal 

Answer (score 13):

Use the following:

> sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:certbot/certbot

and

> sudo apt update

Comment: didn't work for me.  When I execute your second command (sudo apt update) I get another 404, and the same error

Answer (score 4):

I have recently installed `certbot` using this [command](https://tecadmin.net/how-to-setup-lets-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04/):
`sudo snap install --classic certbot`

Comment: Thanks! I was having issues on a Ubuntu 20.04 server and ran this, which worked in the end. Just a comment, this should be carried out as part of the full certbot installation process - instructions at https://certbot.eff.org/lets-encrypt/ubuntufocal-nginx , otherwise might run into some issues with older certbot packages

Comment: The link is now https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=ubuntufocal

Comment: @AndrewSwift , thanks for keeping the answer up to date

Answer (score 1):

[@vinyll](https://stackoverflow.com/users/328117/vinyll) answer helped me that am dealing with `Ubuntu server 20.04`.
There's just a little drawback with it: installs the current head of the repository, which currently is `1.9.0.dev0`.

I suggest to look at [Certbot repository](https://github.com/certbot/certbot/releases) for the desired *release tag* - in my case `v1.8.0` that refers to the just released version `1.8.0` - and to edit the script to "checkout" it.

The script would become (to install `Certbot v1.8.0`):

```
#!/bin/bash

ROOT=~/.certbot-src

# Remove older versions if existing, for a simple re-install/update.
rm -rf $ROOT

# Clone certbot source.
git clone https://github.com/certbot/certbot $ROOT

# Check if python3-venv is installed, and install it otherwise.
CHECK_PACKAGES='python3-venv'
if ! dpkg -s $CHECK_PACKAGES >/dev/null 2>&1; then
  echo "The packages '$CHECK_PACKAGES' are not installed. "
  echo "They will now be installed automatically with 'sudo apt-get install $CHECK_PACKAGES'."
  sudo apt-get install -y $CHECK_PACKAGES
fi

# Checkout the desired release TAG.
cd $ROOT
git checkout v1.8.0 # Replace v1.8.0 with the TAG you chosen

# Setup virtual environment for certbot.
sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev python3-venv gcc libaugeas0 libssl-dev libffi-dev ca-certificates openssl
python3 tools/venv3.py

# Link installed certbot version, so it can used everywhere.
sudo ln -s $ROOT/venv3/bin/certbot /usr/local/bin/
```

---

**NOTE:** if you want to do a clean install and you are going to remove an old *Certbot* version, **do it carefully** - *e.g.* there could be configuration files that would be deleted using `apt purge certbot` or `apt autoremove --purge certbot`, bringing the new *Certbot* installation in an inconsistent state; [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1195603) may help.

---

Comment: Package 'python-virtualenv' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 1):

Some PPA's do not get updated to newer linux version by their creators/maintainers. Therefore, you need to erase them.
To do it without removing the entire PPA you can use this guide:
[safely-remove-ppa-repositories-ubuntu](https://linuxhint.com/safely-remove-ppa-repositories-ubuntu/)

If the PPA version is not compatible with your linux version, you need to update it.
This answer is general for this problem with any PPA errors of that kind so I hope it is the right place to answer it.

Answer (score 1):

I think in recent times the solution is different.

I did two things,
first of all, just install the "certbot" from snap with --classic

> snap install certbot --classic

And remove other packages from "Software & Updates" >> then go to the Tab "Other Software" >> then select all other packages which you want to remove.

[image]

Then in the terminal, you can check it by "Sudo apt update". If there is no issue, you won't get the Error,

[image]