# apt update repository does not have a Release file

Tags: ubuntu, apt

`apt update` fails because a repository cannot be found. It produces the following logs.

```
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:5 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease            
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Ign:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather/ubuntu focal InRelease
Err:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I have Ubuntu version 20.04.2 LTS focal.

Answer (score 8):

This is a simple generalization of [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61853542/10361288) but because I can't comment I am making a post in case this generalization helps others.

The approach that seems to work is to add or remove the repository.

`E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/<org>/<repo>/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.`

Solution:
`sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:<org>/<repo>`

Note: the "-r" flag will remove the repository.

**Example**

So in my case the following worked
`sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:kasra-mp/ubuntu-indicator-weather`