# unable to install the latest nodejs

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm

I have tried many ways, via nvm etc.. nodejs stays stubbornly at v10 which is outdated, what could i do?

```
Err:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-vn/ppa/ubuntu focal Release             
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:67c:1560:8008::19 80]
Err:13 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 2001:ee0:3244::71ab:c39 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-vn/ppa/ubuntu focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'https://deb.nodesource.com/node_8.x focal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60249177/e-the-repository-http-ppa-launchpad-net-certbot-certbot-ubuntu-focal-release)? is not you problem but is similar. Maybe could help.

Comment: i would use nvm

Comment: i did try nvm..

Comment: what platform r u using, mac or windows?

Comment: Ubuntu lts. I basically tried all sensible ways of doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used `nvm install --lts` and it worked